# Jquery - CSS translation with IE

Tags: jquery, css

I want to translate the div called "register_bottom_bar" inside its parent div "register_tile" by 174 pixels upwards using JQuery. I got it to work perfectly in Chrome and Firefox.

How can I do the same in IE? I'm testing it on IE 8.

"register_tile" is a floating div inside a bigger div and "register_bottom_bar" lies at the bottom of "register_tile" with position:relative.

```
$('.register_tile').click(function () {
    $(this).css('opacity', '1');
    $(this).css('background-image', 'none');
    $('.register_bottom_bar').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(0,-174px)');
    $('.register_bottom_bar').css('-moz-transform', 'translate(0,-174px)');
});
```

Comment: Not sure if `translate` is supported in IE8, have you tried using `mordenizr`?

Comment: @badZoke I didn't know about `Modernizr` . I will try it out right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need support for old version of IE (6, 7, 8) you'll need to play with the properties margin / position instead.

```
$('.register_tile').click(function () {
    $(this).css('opacity', '1');
    $(this).css('background-image', 'none');
    $('.register_bottom_bar').css('left', '-174px); // With absolute / relative positioning
    // OR
    $('.register_bottom_bar').css('margin-left', '-174px);
});
```

Comment: Perfect. Worked on IE. Thank you @Gabriel ! Can I apply `transition` to it which will work in IE?

Comment: jQuery animate API is just what I desired for my program. Thank you @Gabriel Again! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any kind of transition effect in older versions of IE.( **IE8 doesn't support CSS3 transforms**)

The only way  I know of to get anything close to it is to use JQuery's `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` methods

you need to use `-ms-transform` for ie9

```
css(' -ms-transform', 'translate(0,-174px)');
```

[**FROM MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/ie/hh393506.aspx)

---

```
-ms-transform: translate(50px,100px); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: translate(50px,100px); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: translate(50px,100px); /* Opera */
-moz-transform: translate(50px,100px); /* Firefox */
```

Comment: I got your point. But the transition works like a charm in other browsers and I want an IE-specific solution. I should at least be able to move `register_bottom_bar` to the desired location without any effects because I want to show some textboxes in place of its default position on click.