# how to translate a div to particular position via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

i want to translate div x and y position through Jquery. it will work in all browsers **like IE 7,IE8, IE9 and IE10** 
i tried like below

```
<div id="s1" style="-ms-transform:translate(159,430)">
            hello
        </div>
```

but not working anymore. how to translate the div to particular x and y position in page that will work in **IE7 and IE8 and IE9 browsers.**

the solution will work in all kinds of IE versions from IE7 to IE10.

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833934/jquery-css-translation-with-ie

Comment: `transform` css property doesn't work for older versions of IE. You should use `margin` or `position` css property instead. have a look at T.J. Crowder's solution below.

Answer (score 0):

-ms-transform is specific to IE browsers. You need to add the other browser specific properties.

```
style="-ms-transform:translate(159,430); transform:translate(159,430); -webkit-transform:translate(159,430);"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `div` absolutely-positioned, and animate it to where you want it to go:

```
$("#s1").css("position", "absolute").animate({
    left: 159,
    top:  430
});
```

In the first bit (the call to `css`) you might want to specify a starting position.

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/aFEzIsI/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/aFEzIsI/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Because IE7 and IE8 doesn't support transform,so you can use this instead:

> $("#s1").css("position", "relative").animate({
>       left: 159,
>       top:  430
>   });

Answer (score -1):

Use units like px etc.

```
<style> 
.tt {
    width: 234px;
    height: 123px;
    background-color: #ABCDEF;
    transform:translate(159px,430px);
    -ms-transform:translate(159px,430px); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:translate(159px,430px); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
</style>
<div id="s1" class="tt">
    hello - use units like px
</div>
```